# Allow all users to vote to close

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close

At present, low-rep users can not assist in finding duplicates and other questions that need closing, apart from flagging for mod attention.

**However, we don’t wish low rep users to be closing questions that should not be closed!**

So why not:

- Let all users vote to close
- Only votes from the high rep users count towards the five votes needed for an “auto close”
- 10K+ users can see a list of all questions with lots of votes to close

(This can be thought of as a way to move work from the diamond mods to the 10K+ users)

Comment: For duplicates the low rep users could just post a comment linking to the possible duplicate. Then high rep users can use this info to close the question.

Comment: "10K+ users can see a list of all questions with lots of votes to close" <-- 10k users can *already* view a list of the questions with the most close votes.  As well as flagged questions/answers.

Comment: @Powerlord, this includes votes from users that "don't count" as they don't have enough rep

Comment: I'm surprised this did so badly. I don't particularly like the idea of allowing < 3k voting that has no actual impact, since it adds confusion to the voting interface, but some other way for people to signal 3ks or 10ks that a question should be closed would be decent. I think there was a suggestion that another flag be added for questions that should be closed, but I don't think anything came of it

Comment: @Shog9, completed?

Comment: @JuanManuel [It's status-completed by way of them being able to flag with close reasons.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/853699#853699)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the [flag dialog redesign](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/) and exposure of standard flags to 10K users, this is *effectively* status-completed.

Answer (score 3):

I see what you're trying to do there, and I like the idea of getting <3k users more involved. I'm not sure that there's enough of a problem to justify a fix, though, especially one that will be as confusing as a second grade/tier of close vote.

Meta has a lot of "don't close all these questions so fast" posts, and a fair number of "why do people keep asking dupes?" questions. When was the last time you heard "too many dupes are remaining open, we need people to close more aggressively"? I can't remember one.

Comment: How many quesions get closed as dupes **after** a few answers have been given and upvoted?

Answer (score 2):

On high-volume sites like Stack Overflow, this really isn't necessary - the 3k+ users will see it and vote to close quickly enough (if it needs to be closed).

On lower-volume sites (i.e. SE betas) this is generally handled by flagging the post for moderator attention, if there's an egregious problem with the question that doesn't fit into the spam/offensive categories.  Seems to work pretty well.

I understand what you're after, I read the last paragraph - but I think that in the cases where there are actually enough well-engaged 10k+ users to pay attention to the "almost votes", there are already more than enough 3k+ users to just close the question, so there'd be a pretty narrow use case for this.